# Query to delete log between range of logdatetime

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AppXmlLogWritter>
  <LogData>
    <LogID>5678201301161640382919</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>20130114164038</LogDateTime>            
  </LogData>
  <LogData>
    <LogID>5678201301161640382920</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>20130115154040</LogDateTime>           
  </LogData>
  <LogData>
  <LogID>5678201301161640382921</LogID>
  <LogDateTime>20130116164042</LogDateTime>          
  </LogData>
</AppXmlLogWritter>
```

For deleting one node i used below xpath query

```
string xpathQuery = "/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[LogDateTime ='" + txtToDate.Text.Trim() + "']";
XmlNodeList objxmlNodeList = objXmldoc.SelectNodes(xpathQuery);
for (int i = 0; i <= objxmlNodeList.Count - 1; i++)
{
    objxmlNodeList[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(objxmlNodeList[i]);
    lblMessage.Text = "Record deleted sucessfully.";
}
```

I am writing log in XML file of various applications. Where user can delete log between range of LogDateTime.How is my XPath query to delete log between range of LogDateTime.

Example: If i have to delete log between datetime range 20130116164038 to 20130116164040.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
strXpathQuery = "/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[LogDateTime >='" + txtFromDate.Text.Trim() + "' and LogDateTime <='" + txtToDate.Text.Trim() +"']";
```

To get all logdata at specified date you can use this:

```
strXpathQuery = "/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[starts-with(LogDateTime, '20130116')]";
```

To get all `logdata` when `LogDateTime` in range from '20130114' to '20130116' you can use this:

```
strXpathQuery = "/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[substring(LogDateTime, 1, 8) >='20130114' and substring(LogDateTime, 1, 8) <='20130116']";
```

Comment: Hamlet :Like query in Xpath possible Means i have to get nodes of this date 20130116

Comment: Exception Details: System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: '/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[starts-with(LogDateTime, '20130116 ']' has an invalid token.

Comment: Hamlet getting me above error when i use strXpathQuery = "/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[starts-with(LogDateTime, '20130116 ']";

Comment: I missed close bracket. Try again.

Comment: Hamlet i have one quetion in xpath query can u please help me

Comment: I have to get xml data from xml file having LogDateTime in range starts with 20130114 to 20130116